# Python XML remove() Realign Element with ElementTree

Tags: python, xml

I would like to remove the entire "value" element, but, when I do, it replaces it with the closing element `</type>` and messes up the formatting. Is there some way to simply delete the row and shift everything up?

XML Code:

```
    <type>
       <child name="someName" />
       <value name="Tier4" />
    </type>
```

Python:

```
for value in type.findall('./value'):
   if value.get('name') == 'Tier4':
   type.remove(value)
```

XML becomes:

```
    <type>
       <child name="someName" />
       </type>
```

Comment: You may need adjust the `.tail` property on the tags.

Comment: Maybe you can try to use lxml for Better Formatting Control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `xml.etree.ElementTree.indent(tree, space='  ', level=0)` to prettify:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_s = """<type>
       <child name="someName" />
       <value name="Tier4" />
    </type>"""

elem = ET.fromstring(xml_s)

for value in elem.findall('./value'):
    if value.get('name') == 'Tier4':
        elem.remove(value)
        
ET.indent(elem, space='  ')
ET.dump(elem)
```

Output:

```
<type>
  <child name="someName" />
</type>
```

Comment: This answer is close enough. I just modified it slightly. I placed it within the for loop of the `<type>` (or elem in your example) and used space='\t' instead of space='  ' 

Thank you!

Comment: @talkinggoat I replaced type in your code, because type is a key word in python and should not used as variable name.